# Scala: how to create an "eager evaluated" list with many elements?

Tags: list, scala, range, evaluation, eager

If I create list like

```
List(10 to 1000)
```

actually，the List only contains a range object, and the list members are generated dynamically when visiting specific elements.

But my requirement is to construct a real List(10,11,12...1000) without having a range object. I found

```
"for ... yield"
```

is also lazy evaluation, thus doesn't match my need. If I don't want to use a for loop to append elements to an empty List, is there a convenient way to do so?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7):

Calling `.toList` on a `Range` forces evaluation:

```
(10 to 1000).toList
```

Answer (score 4):

Even more directly:

```
List.range(10, 1001)
```